# Find choices for $b$ and $B$ so that the boundary-value problem has no solution, exactly one solution and infinitely many solutions

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

> $(a)$ Show that, under the hypothesis of corollary $11.2$, if $y_1$ is the solution to $y''=p(x)y'+q(x)y$ and $y_2(a)=y_2(b)=0$ then $y_2=0$
> $(b)$ Cosider the boundary-value problem, $$y''+y=0,\qquad 0\leq x\leq b,\quad y(0)=0,\quad y(b)=B$$ Find choices for $b$ and $B$ so that the boundary-value problem has no solution, exactly one solution and infinitely many solutions.

Here is the corollary $11.2$,

> Suppose the linear boundary-value problem $$y''=p(x)y'+q(x)y+r(x),\qquad a\leq x\leq b,\quad y(0)=\alpha,\quad y(b)=\beta$$satisfies 
> (i) $p(x),q(x)$, and $r(x)$ are continuous on $[a,b]$
> (ii) $q(x)>0$ on $[a,b]$
> Then the boundary-value problem has a unique solution.

For $(a)$ $y_2=0$ seems a trivial solution, as it satisfy the DE. And from the hypothesis of the corollary of $11.2$ its clear that this solution is unique on $[a,b]$. Is it what the question asked for?

For $(b)$ I have no idea how to conclude anything directly. Hence, I solve the DE and got, $$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$$
Using the boundary condition, got $$c_2=-\frac{B}{e^b-e^{-b}},\qquad c_1=\frac{B}{e^b-e^{-b}}$$
Now, how to conclude anything for those three cases?

I was wondering why the hypothesis $q(x)>0$ was needed? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's a typo. Fixed now. Thanks @LutzLehmann

Comment: In b) you have the wrong basis solutions. Note that relative to a) you have $q=-1$.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know how to solve $(b)$ in the given context. Okay, $q=-1$, how this implies the wrong basis. It will be great help if you add some details @LutzLehmann

Comment: This is the standard example of the harmonic oscillator, with the left BC you get $y(x)=A\sin(x)$.